# Multiple Fetch React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I am using fetch method to make API calls on the server. First, I do a request to have an array of objects (
 `[{"id": 1, "name": "a", "userid": "12"},{"id": 2, "name": "b", "userid": "22"},{"id": 3, "name": "c", "userid": "23"}]`.

After I need one value of this object to give more information ( in this case I need to `userid` to have the information of the user).

For that, I am doing multiple requests to show all at the moment. But doing multiple requests is giving me an error.

> Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {_45,
>   _81, _65, _54}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead or wrap the object using createFragment(object) from
>   the React add-ons. Check the render method of `View`

And this is my code. The second fetch is in `renderImage` function. I put as async but I know that probably is wrong.

```
class Dashboard extends Component{

    constructor(props){
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      dataSource: new ListView.DataSource({
        rowHasChanged: (row1, row2) => row1 !== row2
      }),
      loaded: false,
       datos: '',
    }

    }

    componentDidMount(){
    this.fetchData();
    }

    fetchData(){
        const REQUEST_URL = "XXXXXXX";
        fetch(REQUEST_URL)
        .then((response) => response.json()) //la convertimos a json
        .then ((responseData) =>{
            this.setState({
                dataSource: this.state.dataSource.cloneWithRows(responseData),
            })          
        })
    }

    renderLoadingView(){
        return(
            <View>
            <Text>Cargando...</Text>
            </View>
            )
    }

    async renderImage(userid){
             const REQUEST_URL = "XXXXXXX" + userid;
             const response = await fetch(REQUEST_URL);
             const json = await response.json();
             this.setState({loaded: true})  
             return (<Thumbnail source={{uri: json.imageUrl}} />)

    }

    renderReceta(receta){
    return(       
                    <Card>
                        <CardItem>
                            <TouchableOpacity onPress={()=> this.onUser(receta)}>
                                 {this.renderImage(receta.user_id)}
                            </TouchableOpacity>
                            <Body>
                                <Text>{receta.Titulo}</Text>
                                <Text>{receta.Username}</Text>
                            </Body>
                          </CardItem>
                   </Card>             
        )   
    }

    render(){

        if(!this.state.loaded){
            return this.renderLoadingView();
        }
        else{
            return(
            <Container>
                <Header><Title>H</Title></Header>
                <ListView 
                dataSource={this.state.dataSource}
                renderRow={this.renderReceta.bind(this)}
                />
            </Container>
                )
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: can you make a minimal repo so it's easier to understand what you are trying to do? Also, the question is not detailed enough so I understand your case.

Comment: Yes, first I am doing a fetch to receive some data, after with that data I am doing a second fetch request to show an Image. The first fetch is working okay but in the second is not giving nothing.

Comment: `Objects are not valid as a React child` means you are directly trying to render an object, which you cannot do. Check all of your rendered items. I get the sneaking suspicion that it's in `renderReceta`

Comment: @Andrew Yes, I trying but I don't see the error. Maybe it was because we call the function multiple times, i mean for every "receta" in renderReceta

Answer (score 1):

So, one possible solution is to have a different state for the image. For example:

```
this.state = {
      [...]
      imageLoaded: false
}


  fetchData(){
        const REQUEST_URL = "XXXXXXX";
        fetch(REQUEST_URL)
        .then((response) => response.json()) //la convertimos a json
        .then ((responseData) =>{
            this.setState({
                dataSource: this.state.dataSource.cloneWithRows(responseData),
            })   
            this.renderImage(); //Now you start loading the Image       
        })
    }


renderImage(userid){
             const REQUEST_URL = "XXXXXXX" + userid;
             const response = await fetch(REQUEST_URL);  //You can change this await and just load the fetch in background, does not matter right now. 
             const json = await response.json();
             this.setState({imageLoaded: true, imageUrl: json.imageUrl})  
    }


 renderReceta(receta){
let image = null;
     if (this.state.imageLoaded)
         image = (<Thumbnail source={{uri: this.state.image.imageUrl}} />);
    return(       
                    <Card>
                        <CardItem>
                            <TouchableOpacity onPress={()=> this.onUser(receta)}>
                                 {image}
                            </TouchableOpacity>
                            <Body>
                                <Text>{receta.Titulo}</Text>
                                <Text>{receta.Username}</Text>
                            </Body>
                          </CardItem>
                   </Card>             
        )   
    }
```

This code won't work right away as I have typos and I stripped things but hopefully you would get the point.

PS. I think I answered a similar question before, please consider accepting your answers so they don't keep un resolved.